# Automatic update spring boot docker app using ansible

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ansible

We plan to release spring boot application to customer. In corrent process, every time we release a new version, we have to uninstall the rpm and re install using rpm.
We want to move towards auto update of our application whenever there is a new version available. Essentially customer does not have to deal with updating the applications.
Instead of rpm, we are thinking about docker image, packaged with all dependencies.
. How do achieve this functionality?

Based on what I have read so far, if we package we use ansible + docker to deploy the application, , ansible (using watch tower or custom code) will ping an IP and when discovers a new version, will stop the application, pull the application from destination and then deploy and start. 
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Docker does not make this significantly easier.  Generally the image revision is in the “tag” part of the image name, so you have to discover a new version, stop the old container, and start a new one.  An RPM update is probably easier.

Comment: How you deploy the new containers and what you use to do so is up to you (why not ansible if it works and docker is good for dependency management, the declarative nature makes it easy to rollback) - your description of the deployment would result in downtime, can look into blue / green deployments if that’s a concern. Could i.e. add a playbook execution step to your pipeline(s) to update the deployments after every build of a new image.

Comment: Git+Docker+Jenkins+Proxy makes your application work zero-downtime. All releases will be based on your commit rest will be automated.

Comment: @masseyb downtime is acceptable in this case. Can you explain your suggested approach in detail as an answer?

Comment: @JinnaBalu jenkins will not work here. This is not an internal application.

Comment: Jenkins will work for automation. Ansible is required when you are deleaing with multiple servers.

Comment: Jenkins works with ansible plugin, We trigger an ansible-playbook from the Jenkins server. Ansible will connect to the client-server and run the playbook.

Answer (score 1):

## Steps to automate deployment

### Docker

- Create application and dockerise it with any JDK docker image. We have maven package to dockerise application.

Add Plugin to `pom.xml`

```xml
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>job-demand-service-analytics-processor</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

OR

```xml
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jib-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot</image>
                    </from>
                    <to>
                        <image>websockethandler:latest</image>
                    </to>
                    <container>
                        <entrypoint>
                            <shell>sh</shell>
                            <option>-c</option>
                            <arg>chmod +x /entrypoint.sh &amp;&amp; sync &amp;&amp; /entrypoint.sh</arg>
                        </entrypoint>
                        <ports>
                            <port>8090</port>
                        </ports>
                        <environment>
                            <SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>ALWAYS</SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>
                            <APP_SLEEP>0</APP_SLEEP>
                            <JWT_SECRET_KEY_BASE64>""</JWT_SECRET_KEY_BASE64>
                            ..........
                        </environment>
                        <useCurrentTimestamp>true</useCurrentTimestamp>
                    </container>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

There are many options to dockerise your Spring application

### Git

- Push your code to git server like Bitbucket, Gitlabs, Github and so on.
- Create a master branch for production releases and develop branch for development.

### Jenkins

- Trigger a jenkins job to create a docker image when you commit or merge changes from develop to master when feature is commited to develop.This is based on the hooks we add at git server.
- If the docker image created successfully trigger the job which deploys.

### Reverse Proxy or Load Balancer

- To achive zero downtime, use load balnacer(reverse proxy like NGINX with upstream) running your container in multiple replicas of the container.

This applies for any application. If you have special requirement, update your question with the basic example code and will update the answer with Dockerising and automation steps.

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply. This is not the answer I am looking for. We do have full build pipeline. My problem is software deployed on customer's data center and auto updating when new version is available. We cannot push updates in this case. Customer can chose to opt for auto deployment else they will do manually.

Comment: Manually Build Jenkins Job is an option ofr any user of Jenkins.